# Application.Current <- how does it work?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am going through some WPF example I found.

I have a class here which is inherited from Application:

```
public partial class DataBindingLabApp : Application
{
    private ObservableCollection<AuctionItem> auctionItems = new ObservableCollection<AuctionItem>();

    public ObservableCollection<AuctionItem> AuctionItems
    {
        get { return this.auctionItems; }
        set { this.auctionItems = value; }
    }
}
```

As you can see this class have a property called AuctionItems.
Because it inherits from Application it also contains property called 'Current' which provides access to the Application instance (according to MSDN).

Then in the code I have:

```
((DataBindingLabApp)Application.Current).AuctionItems.Add(item);
```

I do not understand it.

Since we can have many classes which may inherit from Application then how we know that Application.Current actually contains object of class 'DataBindingLabApp'?

Thank you!

Comment: each project has only 1 Application. `Current` is not a property of an instance of `Application`, it is a **static property** of the class `Application`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Visual Studio generates entry point in the partial generated class of custom application type(DataBindingLabApp in your case) by default (You can find it by searching in the root directory of solution).

```
    [System.STAThreadAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    public static void Main() {
        DataBindingLabApp app = new DataBindingLabApp();
        app.InitializeComponent();
        app.Run();
    }
```

And after application has been ran Application.Current contains instanse of DataBindingLabApp.

Comment: Ok, I found it in: 'DataBindingLabApp.g.i.cs' but what would happen if I had two different classes inheriting from Application?

Comment: Only one can be run at the time. Which one is instantiated in the "Main" (entry point). this one will be available in the Application.Current property.

Answer (score 3):

> Since we can have many classes which may inherit from Application

That isn't relevant.  What matters is that there is only ever one *instance* of the Application class.  The one-and-only application that's running.  Be sure to distinguish types from objects.